# Transactions in Google Sheet - Move value from, to

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a document to manage my finances on google sheet, actually, I would like to be able to track the transactions I make between my accounts.
I made [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14A67m3pedcLtv6bff7SSESGu4lZuKvbuN0VQLvfhF1s/edit?usp=sharing) to be able to sum things up.

Actually, I would be able to tell the document i'm making a transaction `from` - `to` (in that case, from content 1 to content 3) and to add a new `value`.
I don't know how to tell google sheet to "move" 25 from content 1 to content 3 or any other content.

Thanks for the precious help.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you'd want to trigger the transactions which start at row 9, and this trigger would update the values `B3:E3` accordingly. Is that the case? In this case, you could create an `onEdit` trigger in Apps Script, and add a checkbox next to each transaction, so that when the checkbox is checked, the transaction is made and `B3:E3` get updated. Would that be appropriate? If that's the case, I'd consider posting an answer explaining this a bit more.

Comment: that's it!
To be more precise, I would like to detect from which `content` it's from and to substract it from that content and to move it to the destination.
So in the exemple sheet I would like to move 25 from `Content 1` to `Content 3`.
But if I change `content 1` to `content 2` in the `from` column, it adjusts correctly.
in the `B3:E3` row.
also, This is supposed to be an extended list, so if I add another row after `B9` it can repeat the operation.
thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer with a possible solution. Let me know if you need more pointers on this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Apps Script [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger so fire the transactions, and use checkboxes to track which transaction should be fired, so that the transaction takes place whenever the corresponding checkbox is checked.

- First, add the checkboxes to the transaction rows by selecting the appropriate cells and click `Insert > Checkbox`.
- Then, open the script bound to your spreadsheet by selecting `Tools > Script editor`, copy the following function, and save the project. Now every time a checkbox is checked, the corresponding transaction takes place in `B2:E3`, and when it is unchecked the transaction gets undone (the `from` and the `to` exchange places, and the money goes the other way):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var checkbox = e.value;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (col === 6 && row > 8) {
    var from = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
    var to = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
    var value = sheet.getRange(row, 5). getValue();
    var valuesToUpdate = sheet.getRange("B2:E2").getValues();
    var fromIndex = valuesToUpdate[0].findIndex(contents => contents === from);
    var toIndex = valuesToUpdate[0].findIndex(contents => contents === to);
    var fromRange = sheet.getRange(3, fromIndex + 2);
    var toRange = sheet.getRange(3, toIndex + 2);
    if (checkbox === "TRUE") { // MAKE TRANSACTION
      fromRange.setValue(fromRange.getValue() - value);
      toRange.setValue(toRange.getValue() + value);               
    } else if (checkbox === "FALSE") { // UNDO TRANSACTION
      fromRange.setValue(fromRange.getValue() + value);
      toRange.setValue(toRange.getValue() - value);    
    }
  }
}
```

This function will fire every time the spreadsheet is edited, but you only want to update the transaction summary whenever the edited cell is a checkbox and this checkbox is checked. The function is checking for that, using the information passed to the `onEdit` function through the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) (`e`), which contains information on the edited cell (its value, its range, etc.):

[image]

#### Reference:

- [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Event Objects: Edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: One last question,
When I check the box, it complete the transaction, but is it possible to undo the action when I uncheck the box?
Also, I would like to change the content 1, 2, 3 & for to my accounts name, as I read the code, you made it possible for a range of contend (Am I right?)
Is it possible to have values like "Current Account" & "Paypal" and anything else?
thanks a lot.

Comment: @pual You're welcome. It would be possible to undo the action when the checkbox is unchecked, but that would require some code reworking. I'll work on it as time permits. About your second question, yes, you could have other names for your contents, as long as those names match in both the individual transactions and the transaction summary.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
You are right, I started renaming these after my question, so I was able to check by myself.

Comment: @pual I updated the code in my answer so that unchecking the checkbox cancels the transaction, I hope that works for you!